# MS Script Control in VBA

Tags: vb.net, vba, vbscript

I generally use VB.Net for programming but I have been delegated to a VBA project that would benefit from using script control for running script. Here is sample code but errors out on the .Run line of code. I can do this in VB.Net easy but can't get it to work in vba.

ERROR = Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignent

```
Option Explicit
Dim sc As New ScriptControl

Sub RunFunctions()
    MsgBox (Eval("2 * PI"))
End Sub

Function Eval(expr As String) As Object
    Dim code As String
    code = "Dim PI" & vbCrLf & _
           "PI = 3.1416" & vbCrLf & _
           " " & vbCrLf & _
           "Function Result" & vbCrLf & _
           "    Result = " & expr & vbCrLf & _
           "End Function"

    sc.Language = "VBScript"
    sc.AllowUI = True
    sc.AddCode (code)
    Dim myparams() as variant

    Eval = sc.Run("Result", myparams)

End Function
```

Using the .Eval function from the script control object runs ok in vba but does not run scripts. Here is an example of that if someone cares to know...

```
Sub SimpleTask()
    Dim expr As String
    sc.Language = "VBScript"
    expr = "2 + 2 * 50"
    MsgBox sc.Eval(expr)
End Sub
```

Comment: When your fingers type the word "error" or "exception" or "access violation", the very next thing they should start typing is what the *exact* error is, including any error message and memory addresses. Writing "it errors out" is absolutely meaningless. If you provide the information, even when the message or address means nothing to you, it can be useful for the people you're asking to help you. Please edit your question and provide the additional details. Thanks. :)

Comment: oh ya i meant to put that in there. got a little trigger happy

Comment: Doesn't "Function Result" require () after it? (little rusty on vbscript so not 100% sure it's a must if no arguments are passed)

Comment: @Eddy i tried adding () but no avail.

Comment: Your Eval function is returning "object": if it really does then you need to use `Set Eval = sc.Run(...)`

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks, but did not work. However you gave me an idea... so i changed the Eval function to return a string, removed the myparams argument from sc.Run("Result") and now it works like a champ.

Comment: @tszoro: please post your answer as an answer (not a question edit) and then accept your own answer.

Comment: Final answer posted. Have to wait 2 days to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final working code for VBA. competent_tech has one for VB.Net.

```
Option Explicit
Dim sc As New ScriptControl

Sub RunFunctions()
    MsgBox (Eval("2 * PI"))
End Sub

Function Eval(expr As String) As String
    Dim code As String
    code = "Dim PI" & vbCrLf & _
           "PI = 3.1416" & vbCrLf & _
           " " & vbCrLf & _
           "Function Result" & vbCrLf & _
           "    Result = " & expr & vbCrLf & _
           "End Function"

    sc.Language = "VBScript"
    sc.AllowUI = True
    sc.AddCode (code)

    Eval = sc.Run("Result")

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is with your parameters to `sc.Run`. Try changing this call from

```
Eval = sc.Run("Result", myparams)
```

to

```
Eval = sc.Run("Result")
```

**Update**

Here is a complete form using your code that compiles and runs correctly:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports MSScriptControl

Public Class Form1

    Dim sc As New ScriptControl

    Sub RunFunctions()
        MsgBox(Eval("2 * PI"))
    End Sub

    Function Eval(expr As String) As Object
        Dim code As String
        code = "Dim PI" & vbCrLf & _
               "PI = 3.1416" & vbCrLf & _
               " " & vbCrLf & _
               "Function Result" & vbCrLf & _
               "    Result = " & expr & vbCrLf & _
               "End Function"

        sc.Language = "VBScript"
        sc.AllowUI = True
        sc.AddCode(code)
        Dim myparams() As Object

        Eval = sc.Run("Result")

    End Function
    Sub SimpleTask()
        Dim expr As String
        sc.Language = "VBScript"
        expr = "2 + 2 * 50"
        MsgBox(sc.Eval(expr))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SimpleTask()
        RunFunctions()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I am getting (Object variable or With block variable not set) on the Eval = sc.Run("Result"). Not sure whats wrong with script.

Comment: Between your answer and Tims answer i was able to resolve. Thanks again.

Comment: @tszoro: Sorry, I totally missed that you were trying to do this in VBA. Which VBA environment are you running this in?

Comment: This is for SolidWorks. Between you and tim i was able to resolve and edited the original post to reflect. I also recomended your answer for folks using VB.Net.